# H2 text width lower than h1 text with

Tags: html, css, alignment

So I have this html code:

```
<div>
    <h1>My h1 title</h1>
    <h2>This is my h2 text which needs to be center aligned and in the same time not to pass the h1 title width</h2>
</div>
```

I want this block to look like this one using just css:

[image: h2 width should not pass h1 width]

Explanation: My h1 will have a bigger font-size and my h2 will have a smaller one. I want that my h2 will be center aligned in the div and the div should have the width of my h1 text. (h1 should stay on 1 line not on many)

How can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: With css. Can you show us what you've tried already

Comment: I've pasted my code in the question. Besides that I've added some font size to them, color and center align to the h2, but I don't know how to make the div width as the h1 width.

Comment: Not sure about the requirement. Created a fiddle. Is this what you wanted? - http://jsfiddle.net/8L9j347r/

Answer (score -1):

You could try a jQuery plugin called [FitText.js](http://fittextjs.com/). Like the name suggests, it fits text to fill a container, as demonstrated [here](http://runnable.com/UmkD_Lm4L1gdAAAc/fittext-example-responsive-text). Putting both of your headers inside the same div and running `$("h1,h2").fitText();` should give them the same width. Check out their [Github page](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js) for more examples.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a tremendously round about (hacky) way of achieving this with just CSS:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waJKGw

```
div {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:300px;
  text-align:center
}
h1 {
  text-align:justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
h1:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height:0;
}
```

The H1 is justified to fill out the entire width of your div container.. Meaning if your div is wide and your h1 text is very short, you get something really ugly - but that's for you to figure out with your content.

Then the H2 is just center aligned.

Comment: If you're going to down vote something that does what you asked for - at least explain why you are down voting.